# What are the rules about incorporating material from StackExchange Chemistry into open educational resources?

Tags: discussion

I think teachers and students can learn a lot from the questions and answers posted on the site. When I tried to compile a list of questions on different topics directly on the site, it was not met with enthusiasm because this is not the purpose of the site ([What are good examples of questions that make college students think about chemistry concepts?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/107760)). So I am wondering about featuring questions and answers offsite, in some type of open educational resource. I have two ideas so far, and wanted to know how to implement them while conforming to the rules of the site:

1. Integrating into worked examples: Open textbooks like OpenStax chemistry have worked examples integrated into the textbook. The textbooks are featured on libretexts.org, so it would be possible to link questions to questions on StackExchange to give more examples, and to show what problems others have ran into when attempting that type of problem. I also use these examples as part of an open tutoring system (https://confchem.ccce.divched.org/2018SpringCCCENLP2), and it would be helpful to link to content on StackExchange from there.
2. Textbook supplement "the muddiest point".There are many excellent conceptual questions and answers on StackExchange. When students learn chemistry, they have to not only learn the definition of a concept, but also internalize it and consolidate it with what they already know. The material on StackExchange is an excellent compendium of misconceptions and misunderstandings chemistry learners encounter. The idea would be to link to some of these on a chapter by chapter (or section by section) basis.

So what are the rules? Are there any restrictions to having links to StackExchange for a non-commercial site? Is it allowed to copy the material or possible to link to a given version (to make sure the link still makes sense even if there are edits on StackExchange)?

Comment: See also the rules about licensing, starting [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/licensing)

Comment: That's actually an interesting topic as long as these "educational resources" remain free. However, I see two downsides: 1. There is a plethora of websites ripping off SE Q&As and doing a machine translation (I encountered multiple Russian and German versions of SO — all of them are horribly translated), which may affect the reputation of your project; 2. since a good portion of the answers contains quotations from closed-sourced published material, this may also be seen similarly to money laundering (or copyright → copyleft (?) transition).

Comment: I think this is a great idea. You may want to look at wikis for inspiration. There will also be potential circularity (for instance libretext and wikipedia are a comon ref). Also, you will have to curate and double check content accuracy, and perhaps improve on Q&As, all of which will in the end be a service to SE chem.

Comment: I am not an expert on this, but I'm not aware of any rules *per se*, beyond CC BY-SA as linked in Loong's comment. You're allowed to copy entire chunks of material from SE, even for commercial usage, as long as you follow the terms described there.