ECHEMI.com - Site that blatantly copy the contents from Chem.SE
The site called ECHEMI.com blatantly copy the contents from chem.SE without any attribution. The latest one was this post where one of the comments mentions the scraper site: https://www.echemi.com/community/are-there-any-sodium-salts-that-are-insoluble-in-water_mjart22041015463_574.html. It copied the content of the Chem.SE post word-to-word (later edits didn't reflect but the first draft or any draft at the time of copying was there). I am sure the commenter meant no harm but we never know their intention.
I raised this topic to the Community Support Team two times where this was the scraper site, but unfortunately they couldn't help. This was their response:

This is not helpful because the scraper site can copy the contents word-to-word without any attribution and make profit out of it. They gave us the option to escalate such issues to the support members but it seems it is not that helpful.  Can the mods kindly check this and/or escalate this to the community staff to review this?
Update: Since the SE staff cannot help on this case, I'd urge everyone to check whether your post has been copied on that site. Based on my conversation with Melanie under Karsten's answer, it seems they are targeting post with huge view count. So, you can review your post/answer which has more view count and verify if you find any copies and mail them for the takedown. I understand this is a manual task, but I guess this is better than nothing. Also, exercise caution while navigating on the site. Be careful and do not click any suspicious URL. Just use search option only.


I'm not sure we have any more say in the matter. When the company decided that it's not worth their effort, then I guess we've been left alone again.

https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4500/what-are-the-rules-about-incorporating-material-from-stackexchange-chemistry-int https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4784/why-do-questions-posted-on-chemistry-se-get-automatically-transferred-to-a-diffe

@Martin-マーチン big sad face :(

@NilayGhosh I read a bit and indeed it is copyright infringement. Sequentially, you can send an email so that they take the content down, then you can send a copyright takedown request, then send a demand letter, and finally take things to court. If you want to escalate this yourself, you have my support, and maybe you can gather more by another post or asking for it...

See this main meta post. You can look at the edit history there to see the change in policy over time. SE used to solicit such sites, but they stopped doing anything about it, even before changing the official policy. There's a "What actions can I take myself?" in the first post, but it basically boils down to "try reporting it to Google, and you can pursue your own independent legal action, I guess, but don't expect any help from us."

"we have no standing," why not? Is the CC-by-SA administered by the people asking or answering questions? I would be happy to file a DMCA for anything I've written that's been copied.

@MetalStorm that seems what Karsten did in the answer below and it can takedown only that particular post rather than the whole site. And it seems like they are not responding directly to us but they are aware that we are sending them mails.

@R.M. more big sad face :(

I sent them an email (to service@echemi.com), asking them to add an attribution or take it down:

Hi,
This article on your site, https://www.echemi.com/community/ramachandran-plot-phi-psi-dihedral-angle-convention-for-zero-positive-and-negative-value-old-and-new_mjart2203306722_480.html
is a copy of this page on chemistry.stackexchange.com: Ramachandran plot Phi(ϕ) Psi(ψ) dihedral angle Convention for Zero, Positive and Negative value- old and new.
The license for the stackexchange content is CC-BY-SA. I am the author of one of the answers, but I am not attributed on your site.
Please add an attribution or take down the material.
Sincerely,
Karsten

It's been 4 business days without an answer. I don't expect they will answer at all. However, the link does not work anymore, so either they took it down or they moved it elsewhere.

Hi Karsten. Thank you for your action. It seems they won't respond to us but they are aware that they received the email and took down the post to avoid any legal repercusssion. And this is only one post. There are hundreds of posts copied from here and not limited to Chem SE. I saw posts from bio SE, phy SE. They really scraped them without our notice.

And one more point about that site. It seems it is a vendor to distribute chemicals similar to Alibaba etc. Not sure how legit it is, so if we end up in a position to take down the site, we need more that just sending mails to the site to take down material. We need the support of Stack exchange which unfortunately are not longer pursuing towards these scraper sites :(

@NilayGhosh Is there any way to search for questions or answers we posted? I would like to get mine taken down.

It's hard to find which exact post they have copied from. The previous two posts I have found by chance encounter (Google search entry) and they looked eerily similar to our contents. When I compared them side-by-side, that's when I found they are totally copying. I just made a quick observation on that site and looks like they are targeting post with huge view count.

These are same examples I found:  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/74963/repairing-acetone-damage-and-discoloration-to-plastic, https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37280/whats-the-difference-between-%ce%94g-and-%ce%94g, https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/53455/conversion-of-a-value-between-g-gmol-and-lb-lbmol @MelanieShebel

@MelanieShebel I found one of your question copied in that site: https://www.echemi.com/community/there-s-an-absolute-zero-is-there-an-absolute-hot_mjart2204141386_478.html

And this one as well: https://www.echemi.com/community/why-are-most-glow-in-the-dark-things-green_mjart2204083061_721.html
